# Is there any reference in Hindu or ancient texts to the Deccan Trap volcano eruptions which wiped out life on Earth?

Tags: shiva, yuga

[This article](http://www.sobrightandbeautiful.net/blog/volcanoes-versus-dinosaurs) states that gigantic volcano eruptions in the area of Deccan in modern India were the cause of life extinction on Earth 66 million years ago. About 4 subsequent volcano eruptions spewed poisonous gases and ash into the air, blocking sunlight and wiping out most lifeforms on Earth.

1. How does this period of destruction tally with Kalpa/Yuga theory?
2. Do Hindu / other ancient texts have any reference to this event?
3. Is there any connection to Shiva's destructive force?

Answer (score 2):

Yuga theory states that four yugas are of length 4.32 million years. Currently 28<sup>th</sup> chaturyuga is going on. So 66 million is 13<sup>th</sup>/14<sup>th</sup> chaturyuga. Currently we don't what exactly happened in that period. There is very less information available of period behind this chaturyuga. (3.9million years ago)